# Error build u-boot with Openssl (can not find Openssl function body)

Tags: openssl, u-boot

I try to build u-boot (git clone https://source.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot.git)

First make .config for Beaglebone - it`s ok:

`make am335x_boneblack_vboot_defconfig`

I had build Openssl by script

```
    export INSTALL_DIR=/home/user/opensslArm
    export CROSSCOMP_DIR=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin

    ./Configure linux-generic32 shared --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --openssldir=$INSTALL_DIR/openssl --cross-      compile-prefix=$CROSSCOMP_DIR/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

And it`s ok.

Try to build u-boot

```
    LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/opensslArm/lib CFLAGS=-I/home/user/opensslArm/include make ARCH=arm     CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-  -lcrypto
```

Errors of output:

tools/sunxi_toc0.o: In function `toc0_verify_header': sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x4f5): undefined reference to` RSA_set0_key'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x50c): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x52a): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_e'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x5f0): undefined reference to `RSA_set0_key' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x702): undefined reference to` RSA_set0_key'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x719): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x726): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x743): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x750): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_e'
tools/sunxi_toc0.o: In function `toc0_set_header': sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xaa5): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_d'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xafe): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_d' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xd81): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xda9): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xde9): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xe11): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf14): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf29): undefined reference to `BN_bn2binpad' sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf3b): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_e'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf50): undefined reference to `BN_bn2binpad' tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function` prepare_ctx':
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl' ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to` EC_GROUP_order_bits'
tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function `ecdsa_check_signature.isra.3': ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x3ad): undefined reference to` ECDSA_SIG_set0'
tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function `ecdsa_sign': ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x497): undefined reference to` ECDSA_SIG_get0'
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x4ae): undefined reference to `BN_bn2binpad' ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x4c0): undefined reference to` BN_bn2binpad'
tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function `ecdsa_add_verify_data': ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x68d): undefined reference to` EC_GROUP_order_bits'
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x6d3): undefined reference to `EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates' tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o: In function` rsa_sign':
rsa-sign.c:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl' tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o: In function` rsa_get_params':
rsa-sign.c:(.text+0x973): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_key' rsa-sign.c:(.text+0x9c0): undefined reference to` RSA_get0_key'
tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o: In function `rsa_add_verify_data': rsa-sign.c:(.text+0xe27): undefined reference to` EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scripts/Makefile.host:104: recipe for target 'tools/dumpimage' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/dumpimage] Error 1
Makefile:1846: recipe for target 'tools' failed
make: *** [tools] Error 2

For example function RSA_get0_n is contained in libcrypto.so

`nm -D libcrypto.so | grep RSA_get0_n`

00164549 T RSA_get0_n

I try to build u-boot binary files